# Jquery "live" is fine but "on" is not on jsfiddle

Tags: jquery

There must be something wrong. I don't know what? [see this on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nawazhi/h75BD/).

```
/*
$("p").live("click", function(){
  $(this).after("<p>Another paragraph!</p>");
});
*/


$("p").on("click", function(){
  $(this).after("<p>Now Click Me...Another paragraph!</p>");
});
```

I have selected jquery 1.7.2. and `live` is working fine  but `on` does not attach click event. as per jquery documentation, `on` should be working as `live` has been deprecated. Any idea?

Comment: Strange..  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nawazhi/h75BD/) working fine for me..

Comment: @undefined In question Rab mentioned that on does not attach click event. But its working right.

Comment: @Rab **It is working exactly how it should. What do you expect it to do?** By the way, I still use `live` even though it's deprecated because it is easier to use than `on`. :)

Comment: I dont see it working. when I create a new paragraph dynamically. the click is not attached

Comment: @RabNawaz You did not bind it properly. This is the proper way: http://jsfiddle.net/NathanJohnson/h75BD/6/

Comment: ok, thanks, but I thought, on is binded as live is.

Comment: `on` works a bit differently than `live`. You have to bind `on` to a parent element and then the second parameter will be the actual element that you want to have the user click on. I like using `live` much better than `on` since you don't have to worry about all this extra stuff, but for some reason the jQuery Team deprecated it.

Comment: but on api.jquery.com/on. search "Example". it binds it as I am

Comment: The first example is not for dynamically created elements though. You need to have a look at the eighth example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not binding the `on` event correctly, you need to bind it to a parent

```
$("body").on("click", "p", function(){ });
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h75BD/2/

Binding it using the `$('selector').on()` syntax works exactly the same as `.click()`, the event is not delegated. If you want it to be delegated (aka live), you need to use the `$('parent').on('click', 'selector')` syntax.

Comment: thanks. but on api.jquery.com/on. search "Example". it binds it as I am

Comment: From the docs: `Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()`. If you want the events to be delegated (aka live), you need to call `.on` on the parent and pass it a selector. Look at the very last example on the page.

Comment: @RabNawaz Have a look at the eighth example. That shows you how to bind events to dynamically created elements (pretty much what you were trying to do in the jsfiddle)

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `.on()` works well.

But remember, `$(some_selector).live('click', function(){})` is not equal `$(some_selector).on('click', function(){})`, but

```
$(document).on('click', some_selector, function(){});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to delegate for dynamically created elements.  So you should use something like this.    `body` can be replaced with any parent element of `p`

```
$('body').on('click','p',function(){
     $(this).after("<p>Now Click Me...Another paragraph!</p>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h75BD/1/

This way the event bubbles up the the parent element and is handled there since `body` is there when the dom is ready.  The way you were doing it, it will only attach to `p` elements that were there when dom is ready.

Answer (score 2):

"on" doesn't work quite like that. You call "on" on a parent element that will have the children elements dynamically attach to it. In this case, it would be body.

```
$('body').on('click', 'p', function(){});
```

Answer (score 2):

**On attaches event to descendant of element being selected.** You are attaching *on* to *p* that does not have descendant and newly added *paragraph p* is inserted after the p tag to whom you added on handler so it does not come under it (Newly added *p* is not descendant of *p* to whom you attached click with *On*.

To explain what I mean put existing *p* in div and newly added *p* will be descendant of the parent div and on will be attached to every newly added *p* which is descendant of div with id div1.

Selector which is second argument is to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element [**Reference**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h75BD/5/)**

```
$("#div1").on("click", "p", function(){
  $(this).after("<p>Now Click Me...Another paragraph!</p>");
});
```

Or you can put it on document to attach click on every element p added to document.

```
$(document).on("click", "p", function(){
  $(this).after("<p>Now Click Me...Another paragraph!</p>");
});
```

​

​